# How to implement TabBarView with swipe to refresh in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, swiperefreshlayout

I want to implement swipe to refresh or pull to refresh with tab  bar view in flutter...any suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RefreshIndicator
Refer https://medium.com/codechai/adding-swipe-to-refresh-to-flutter-app-b234534f39a7

```
RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _pullRefresh,
          child:<<your child>>
```

Comment: body: TabBarView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new PageView.builder()]) >> my view contain like this how can i re arrage @dev

Comment: 'dynamic' doesn't extend 'T extends State<StatefulWidget>'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'T extends State<StatefulWidget>'.darttype_argument_not_matching_bounds
The name 'RefreshIndicatorState' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/material/refresh_indicator.dart (via package:flutter/material.dart)' and 'package:pull_to_refresh/src/internals/indicator_wrap.dart (via package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart)'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one